# What is a charge on a conductive plate with a voltage between itself and a distant ground?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, charge, electrically-conductive

You'll find numerous examples of equations of capacitors and how to calculate the charge upon the parallel plates.  But what is the charge on a conductive plate with a voltage between itself and a (distant) ground?  In much searching, I can't seem to find any material on that specific, although I know one can charge up balloons, cats and people electrostatically.  And probably wombats too.

Comment: Why a plate? When the other electrode is distant enough I suspect the shape ceases to matter, so it could be, say, a sphere.

Comment: Something flat with known thickness and dimensions that lends itself to a quick calculation.  Good point though.

Comment: Look for capacitance calculations. Sphere to sphere where distance >> radii is a common problem (I remember solving it in skule), sphere to infinite plane may be somewhat more challenging.

Comment: @TedJackson I think you may be being a bit sly. I may be wrong. In any case, I think you know the calculations are easier for regular capacitors because of the assumption that some of the surfaces are quite close to each other, so the charges *elsewhere* can be ignored as most of the charge difference will be kept at the nearby surfaces. If you are an infinite distance away (and I've no idea about the shapes involved, as yet, but are you serious about finite shapes?) then the charges will be distributed over entire surfaces and I think fringe fields dominate. Draw a diagram, I say.

Comment: @TedJackson Sphere will be radially symmetrical - easy geometry. Find an equation for one sphere inside another, then find the limit as the outer sphere's radius goes to infinity

Answer (score 0):

\$ Q = C*V\$

the charge is related to the capacitance between the two plates.

Comment: So, you're saying the charge is zero.  But electrostatically charged balloons that stick to wombats surely have SOME charge.

Comment: I said its dependent on the voltage and the capacitance

Comment: I don't think you read my question closely, Voltage Spike.  It's not a capacitor per se any more than a lone charged balloon or an unpaired plate is a capacitor.  You're just showing me one more capacitor equation.  I said I've seen a bunch of those.  This is what I was afraid of.  No one seems to know.  Sigh...

Comment: Two non parallel plates still have capacitance, a close plate and a far away ground plane still have capacitance and true above equation applies. The trick is finding the capacitance

Comment: As dist goes to infinity, C goes to zero according to C=Q/V=e*A/d=e0*er *h*w/d, where e0, er, h, w and d are permeability of free space, relative permeability, plate height, width and dist between plates.  I'm frankly trying to see if I can calculate the high voltage (relative to earth ground) supplied by a cheap electrostatic voltage generator module (or Van Der Graff generator) applied to the leaves of a DIY metal leaf electroscope by measuring the leaves' repulsive deflection instead of measuring that large electrostatic voltage directly with an expensive electroscope.  Ballpark it anyway.

Comment: The 'trick' is what I'm trying to determine.

Comment: You can measure it somewhat, you have to find a model for capacitance, which means if you have a vandergraff generator, it's going to look like a sphere with a ground plane, and the capacitance can be calculated for that with EM theory. The ideal models usually assume some kind of an infinite ground plane. If you are trying to do this for experiments sake, there is more than one 'plate' in the real world if you have the generator sitting in a room with a fixed ground plane. Any other object can create capacitance. Even the base of the generator will create it's own capacitance.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Can you point me in the direction of one of those ideal models?  An internet page that discusses their physics / EM theory?  I've looked but failed to find anything but the simple sandwich capacitor equation.

Answer (score 0):

Here we go.  It's a start, anyway.  My ultimate intention is to calibrate a DIY electrometer (a spark gap voltmeter, Henley's electrometer, and a pith ball electroscope).  This page helps.  Enjoy.

[https://www.coe.ufrj.br/~acmq/hvmeasurements/](https://www.coe.ufrj.br/%7Eacmq/hvmeasurements/)